# octavia: what is the loadbalancer IP assigned to?

Tags: openstack, tripleo

I am trying to understand how Octavia is put together. I created a loadbalancer on a vlan network. It was assigned an address of 10.40.0.7. When I do openstack loadbalancer list, I see a vip_address of 10.40.0.7 which is not assigned to any amphorae.

I want to understand where the loadbalancer address is mapped. It is not a host. I can't ssh to that address. Perhaps it is the amphora driver but what exactly is that?  I can't see that address find it in any namespace. I can't see it assigned to any bridge. What is it assigned to?

Thanks

Ranga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not a host.

It is a host! An amphora is just a nova server -- the same thing you get when you run `openstack server create`.  The difference is that the amphora is owned by the `service` project, so you'll only see it if you were to run (as admin) `openstack server list --all-projects`. For example:

```
$ openstack --os-cloud as_me loadbalancer list
+--------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
| id                                   | name    | project_id                       | vip_address | provisioning_status | provider |
+--------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
| 64a6a56d-beeb-4ee2-b495-1cdc26ffd399 | test_lb | 0ac1e30189da48b387cf3c2f5582b2a3 | 10.254.0.6  | ACTIVE              | octavia  |
+--------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+

$ openstack --os-cloud as_admin server list --all-projects | grep amphora
| f6cd75fe-8513-4aae-bee9-af9362525703 | amphora-50dddb41-decf-4b3b-bb7a-f35a751d74af | ACTIVE | lb-mgmt-net=172.24.0.16; test_lb_net=10.254.0.11; test_net1=10.0.1.5; test_net0=10.0.0.4  | octavia-amphora-13.0-20181107.1.x86_64 | octavia_65  |
```

If you look at that server, you'll see it has several ip addresses:

- The one you assigned to it when created the loadbalancer, and
- A management network address
- Addresses on any subnets to which it is attached

You can ssh into the amphora using the management network address. You should be able to reach it from your controllers.  You'll need the appropriate ssh key; where to find that probably depends a lot on how you installed things.  I'm using tripleo, and it looks as if the install uses `~/.ssh/id_rsa` from the stack user for the amphora ssh key.

```
[controller ~]$ ssh -i amphora_private_key cloud-user@172.24.0.7
Last login: Thu Nov 15 22:01:16 2018 from 172.24.0.6
[cloud-user@amphora-7d48e10b-5ba4-42c9-bcd5-941d224b2a46 ~]$
```

**Update**

The loadbalancer VIP is assigned to an interface inside a namespace on
the amphora.  Given the above configuration, I see:

```
[root@amphora-50dddb41-decf-4b3b-bb7a-f35a751d74af ~]# ip netns
amphora-haproxy (id: 0)
[root@amphora-50dddb41-decf-4b3b-bb7a-f35a751d74af ~]# ip netns exec amphora-haproxy ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:07:d2:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.254.0.11/24 brd 10.254.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.254.0.6/24 brd 10.254.0.255 scope global secondary eth1:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe07:d226/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:21:9a:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.4/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe21:9ad1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:2a:63:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.5/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global eth3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe2a:6358/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: I can ssh into the amphora. However, I have an address that is not assigned to any amphora. I see a VIP address in openstack loadbalancer list. What is this assigned to? I can log into the amphorae.

Comment: I think I found my answer. It is assigned to an openstack port.

Comment: Right.  When you `openstack loadbalancer show` your load balancer, you can see the port id.

Comment: Still looking for what IP abstraction that the port maps to ( i.e. is it a namespace, veth pair in a namespace or virutal device .. what exactly?)

Comment: The vip is assigned to an interface in a namespace on the amphora.  See my update to the answer for details.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  Clears up a mystery. I like to know how things work conceptually before I use anything.